# Using Matlab to read binary data from file

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I'm currently trying to read data from a `.surf` file using Matlab. (I realise there will probably be quite a lot of other questions similar to this, but each is specific to its own problem, and I wasn't able to find a duplicate of what I'm about to ask; if someone else does and marks this as duplicate... apologies!)

This is what the readme for the data files says:

```
All of the files consist of 1-byte values, except for the
surface (surf) files, which consist of 4-byte floating-point
values.  The 1-byte phase values denote the phase scaled and
quantized to the range 0-255.  The 1-byte correlation and
mask values denote the weights 0-1 scaled and quantized to
the range 0-255.
```

I have been able to read a `.phase` file without any problems using

```
fn = 'spiral.257x257.phase';
f = fopen(fn);
fin = fread(f, [257, 257], 'uint8');
fclose(f);
```

However, I'm unable to read the surf file. I have tried `single`, `float32` and `real*4`, the three options under 'Floating-point numbers' in the Matlab documentation for `fread`, as well as `uint`, `uint32`, `int`, `int32` and `long`, which are the other options for 4-byte data. None of these give the correct solution at all - not even just the wrong scaling; they're completely off.

I'm pretty stuck for ideas; any advice (including general advice) would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a different byte-order for reading? You can set it with the `machinfmt` property of `fread`.

Comment: I haven't, no. Would this reorder the matrix, or does it do something completely different? At the moment, the data is well off, and not just mis-ordered. For example, the maximum value is supposed to be maybe 10 or 20, but is coming up as 10^9 or even 10^37! If, however, it does something completely different, then I'll look into it.

Comment: It won't reorder the matrix, it is just a convention on byte order in a representation of each number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Awesome, that's fixed it. I used `float` and `b`, that is big-endian ordering. If I'm honest, I have no idea what these things mean; I just started going through them in order!

Comment: Oh a strongly related note, are `float` and `float32` the same. Also, I got the same answer with `single` and also using big-endian ordering, 64-bit long data. Is this to be expected?

Comment: Endianness is quite simple really. When we write decimal numbers, we always write them in a 'big endian' format - the first digit is the most significant (eg in '104', the hundreds come first, then the tens, then the units). 'Small endian' is the opposite - the units would come first, then the tens, then the hundreds.

Comment: A float is a number with a 'floating point' ie the position of the decimal place isn't fixed, so they can represent a massive range of values. `single` is matlab slang for a 32-bit float (`float32`) so they are the same; the same applies to `double` and `float64`. If you just use `float`, I have not idea how matlab decides whether to use a 32- or 64-bit float (though I think matlab defaults to use `double` floats). In general, a 32-bit float my be stored in a 64-bit float, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, not actually that complicated! I think Matlab stores `float` and `float32` as the same - in the documentation, it gives the size as 32-bits for `float32` (and of course 32-bits for `float32`, but 64-bits for `float64`). That does seem weird since if you just type, eg, `a = 0` into the command window, it stores `a` using double precision. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, though. I'm a mostly-pure mathematician doing a numerical analysis summer project, so most of this stuff is pretty foreign to me!